# CodeIgniter - adding data to session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Just started learning CodeIgniter and making a small project with it. I have been trying to add an userlevel to the session but everytime i try to echo it, it doesnt display anything. Heres my model code:

```
function get_userlevel($username){
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
}
```

And my controller code:

```
$userlevel['records'] = $this->membership_model->get_userlevel($this->input->post('username'));

            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'userlevel' => $records['userlevel'],
                'logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

And the code to display the userlevel ->

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata['userlevel'] ; ?>
```

Can anyone help this noobie out? :)

Answer (score 0):

While `$this->session->userdata['userlevel'];` is technically valid and probably should work, you should use the `userdata()` function instead, in case a future release of CI declares the Session class `userdata` property as `protected` or `private`:

```
$this->session->userdata('userlevel');
```

More importantly, your model is trying to find too many results and returning an array of results, rather than just one. Try this instead:

```
function get_userlevel($username){
    $query = $this->db
        ->where('username', $username)
        ->limit(1)
        ->get('users');
    return $query->row();
}
```

`row()` returns a single row or `FALSE`. Before you were building an array of many rows (although there is only one expected). I think this is the root of your problem.

In addition, there's a little dyslexia in your code. You're not using the correct variable. You're assigning the model's result to `$userlevel['records']` while assigning `$records['userlevel']` to the session.

For future debugging, `var_dump($data)` before passing it into the session to make sure it's what you think it is, and always make sure `error_reporting()` is on full blast.

Answer (score 0):

use parentheses to access 'userdata' and assign it to an array to be able to work with what it holds.

```
<?php  
if($this->session->userdata('userlevel')) {
    $arr = $this->session->userdata('userlevel');
    var_dump($arr['username']);
    var_dump($arr['userlevel']);
    var_dump($arr['logged_in']);
}
?>
```

Comment: `isset($this->session->userdata('userlevel'))` is always `TRUE`, because the function returns either the value or `FALSE`. This is a debugging technique, not so much a solution, and can be compressed to `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())`

Comment: you was right about `isset()` consider it a mistype, as for `var_dump()` i just wanted to show him how to access his `userdata()` array. `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())` returns ALL the `userdata()` which he doesn't needs right now.